# Google Crawler: Mark as Fixed is not helping

Tags: google-search-console

I migrated my site 2 years back (flash based to responsive). But Google crawler still complains that the old files are not reachable. Few times, I marked them fixed in the webmaster tools site. But still producing those errors. Some one mentioned in Google forum, just leave them as errors for a while and crawler marks itself these as obsolete after few attempts. This approach is also not helping. The site is a *nix GoDaddy-site with .htaccess file. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: What kind of webserver are you running, and do you have control over it yourself?

Comment: My site is deployed in GoDaddy which means I have limited admin control.

Comment: Do you have a cPanel with a .htaccess file?

Comment: Or is it Windows hosting, you're using?

Comment: No. This is on UNIX and I have access to .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work if you set up an http re-write rule for your web server, defining the content as `http 301`, [Moved Permanently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301). Then the crawl bot will start looking in the new place.

So, the bot request:

```
GET /index.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.org
```

And the appropriate server response:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.example.org/index.asp
```

I've done this with success before, on a forum site where we changed URL format after a year or so.

If the amount of links are not too big, you can redirect each and one of them by doing this in .htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 /old-page.html http://example.com/new-page.html
Redirect 301 /another-old-page.html http://example.com/another-new-page.html
```

And it seems that the [mod_rewrite is enabled by default](https://godaddy.com/help/how-do-i-use-mod-rewrite-899), so only type your redirects, and you're home free. When you've had them for a while, they can be taken away again.

Comment: Can you test and see, @jprism?